# How to remove stopwords with Russian documents?

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a bit of a problem with the [tm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) R package for cleaning text documents.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
library("tm")

# import text files in corpus text – ok
c_txt <- Corpus((DirSource(directory = ".", pattern ="txt", 
                encoding = "UTF-8")), readerControl = list(language = "rus"))

# convert to Lower Case – ok
txt_cl <- tm_map(c_txt, tolower)

# remove Stopwords - not working
txt_cl <- tm_map(txt_t, removeWords, stopwords("russian"))
```

I am inspecting the file `russian.dat` which is located in the subdirectory `tm\stopwords`. There I can notice strange characters -- not Russian stopwords, although it is UTF-8 encoding.

Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user4212, what is your system locale? Sometimes you can have problems when working with one language but in different locale.

Comment: @user4212, the `txt_t` is undefined in your code. Can you include R output so we can see the error more clearly?

Comment: @user4212, I suspect that file  `russian.dat` is corrupted. Try asking package **tm** maintainers.

Comment: Wouldn't this question fare better on SO?

Comment: Thanks all for help.
My system locale: `LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251` 

My output for control: `txt_cl[[1]] or txt_cl[[2]]`

Yes. `txt_t` is undefined, correct - `c_txt`.

Answer (score 5):

I've just downloaded the Windows binary version of `tm` from CRAN: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html

The `russian.dat` file that's included there isn't UTF-8, but is encoded using [KOI-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-R). I am unfamiliar with the inner workings of `tm`, but you state that you think the file is UTF-8. I am wondering if the problem has to do with the different character encodings?

You could you try to figure out the encoding of your file using http://2cyr.com/decode/ and specifying Autodetect as the source encoding.

Comment: Thanks’ @aix. Source encoding `Koi8-u` displayed as `Iso8859-5`. I am changed `russian.dat` in `utf-8`. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Russian texts in  R (RStudio), you have to make sure everything (I mean, everything - the R code and all other files you'll be sourcing and reading) are encoded in UTF-8.  -  To ensure that, you can all files with Save As with Encoding.

Finally, if you work in RStudio, 
create a file .Rprofile, which contains one line Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "russian") and place it in your home or working directory - 
as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307007/printing-utf-8-characters-in-r-rmd-knitr-bookdown